# std::sort on vector of vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std

I'm actually trying to sort a vector of Descriptor basing on a vector included in the Descriptor

```
float           xi, yi;     // Descriptor location
vector<double>  fv;         // The feature vector
```

(here the vector named fv)
What I want to do is to search in the vector of Descriptor (I will name it Vec_Desc for more clarity from now) the dimension that have the most variance
to do so, I use :

```
double Tree::_get_mean(vector<Descriptor>& vec, int indice)
{
    double sum = 0;
    int size = vec.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += vec[i].fv[indice];
    }
    sum /= size;
    return sum;
}

double Tree::_get_variance(vector<Descriptor>& vec, int indice)
{
int size = vec.size();
double var = 0;
double mean = _get_mean(vec, indice);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var += ((vec[i].fv[indice] - mean) *  (vec[i].fv[indice] - mean)) / size;
    }
    return var;
}

int Tree::choose_dimension(vector<Descriptor>& vec)
{
    double var = _get_variance(vec, 0);
    int indice = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < vec[0].fv.size(); i++) {
         if (var > _get_variance(vec, i)) {
            var = _get_variance(vec, i);
            indice = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I want to sort the vec_desc based on the dim I found.
Tried to do like this :

```
class _compare {
    int step;
public: 
     _compare(int s) : step(s) {}

    bool operator()(const vector<double>& p1, const vector<double>& p2) {
        return p1[step] < p2[step];
    }
};

void Tree::_sort_vector(vector<Descriptor>& vec, int i)
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), _compare(i));
}

void Tree::sort_vector(vector<Descriptor>& vec)
{
    _sort_vector(vec, choose_dimension(vec));
}
```

But with this, I will sort vec_desc using his own values, and not the values contained in the fv's...
How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using a C++11 compiler?  If so, I would suggest you change to using `lambda` functions instead of functors and utilize this feature.  You more than likely will be able to more easily achieve what you're trying to achieve doing things that way.  Also, it isn't a good thing to start your names with underscores.

Comment: This `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), _compare(i));` shouldn't compile since `_compare::operator()` takes `vector<double>`, not a `Descriptor`! Or is there an operator to convert `Descriptor` to `vector<double>`? You seem to not be showing the whole code.

Comment: See here: [cppreference[(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) "*The types `Type1` and `Type2` must be such that an object of type `RandomIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them.*"

Comment: PaulMcKenzie I use underscore when it's a function that will be used only in other functions :)
I'm not sure that lambda could help me this time ^^

Iksemyonov My problem was actually there, but I'm pretty stupid i think, because the solution was easy. I'm on it for 6 days now, and i'm probably tired :p
Thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator is incorrect - since you are sorting `vector<Descriptor>` it has to compare two instances of `Descriptor` not `vector<double>`:

```
class _compare {
    int step;
public: 
     _compare(int s) : step(s) {}

    bool operator()(const Descriptor& d1, const Descriptor& d2) const {
        return d1.fv[step] < d2.fv[step];
    }
};
```

Comment: Oooooh yes! I'm kinda stupid, the solution was obvious! 
Thanks a lot ! :)